# Phing PropertyTask - what is a fallback project scope?

Tags: phing

**Update:** This question is outdated. The `fallback` attribute can no longer found in the manual.

---

According to the Phing User Guide, [PropertyTask](https://www.phing.info/guide/chunkhtml/PropertyTask.html) provides a `fallback` attribute to specify a "fallback project scope" in case a reference cannot be found.

I tried to run this but it's obviously wrong:

```xml
<property name="test1" value="ok" />
<property name="test2" refid="nonExistentRef" fallback="test1" />
<echo>${test2}</echo>
```

Result:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Reference::getReferencedObject() must be an instance of Project, string given, called in [...] classes/phing/tasks/system/PropertyTask.php on line 339 [...]

Can you provide me with a working usage example?

Answer (score 1):

fallback expect a *Project* instance, and I think that it cannot be passed from build file.

Did you try with:

```
<property name="test1" value="ok" />
<property name="test2" refid="test1" />
<echo>${test2}</echo>
```

Output:

```
  [echo] ok
```

Comment: Could be. It's quite a mystery. Why would there be a `fallback` attribute if it's not meant to be used? A remaining fossil of an earlier version perhaps?

Comment: I don't know, but look lines 250 (definition of setFallback) & 339 of PropertyTask class https://github.com/phingofficial/phing/blob/master/classes/phing/tasks/system/PropertyTask.php#L250 and  https://github.com/phingofficial/phing/blob/master/classes/phing/types/Reference.php#L65 to view that is not possible to cast an string to *Project*